# how can i place order using disabled product from admin create order only in magento2?

Tags: magento2.3, adminhtml, place-order

I want to place order for disabled product too only from admin create order.

so i want to know where i can skip quote validation so that magento2 could allow me place order.

when i am placing order i am getting below notification.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is not allowed by Magento which is technically correct, if you still want to place order you can place back-order please refer below link:

[Backorder](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory-backorders.html)

[Also see this link](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/Create-backend-order-with-disabled-product/m-p/448639)

If you still want this their are several ways to do so:
1). You can customise backend part fully and load shipping and payment methods which is to tough.
2). You can create same attribute like status and this will work only on frontend. But you have to do lot of customisation in lot of files on frontend.

**NOTE:**  It is too risky to follow these 2 ways for future and current stability of website. So my suggestion is to you should follow Magento ways only(backorder).